# Python get Digital coordinates from xml.file

Tags: python, coordinates

I'm new to python and now I'm trying use python to read 2D digital coordinates from an xml which is get from andriod application. Part of the xml file should be like the following code(in the orginal file I have lots of such node):

`<node bounds="[956,63][1080,210]" selected="false" password="false" long-clickable="true" scrollable="false" focused="false" focusable="true" enabled="true" clickable="true" checked="false" checkable="false" content-desc="search" package="com.android.settings" class="android.widget.Button" resource-id="" text="" index="0"/> </node>`

and what I need is try to get every node bounds(the pair of 2D coordinates) from xml file, how to do that in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `xml.dom` library in Python to fulfill your task:

```
from xml.dom import minidom

nodes = minidom.parse("mydoc.xml").getElementsByTagName("node")

for node in nodes:
    print(node.getAttribute("bounds"))
```

XML File Content I used:

```xml
<nodes>
    <node bounds="[956,63][1080,210]" selected="false" password="false" long-clickable="true" scrollable="false" focused="false" focusable="true" enabled="true" clickable="true" checked="false" checkable="false" content-desc="search" package="com.android.settings" class="android.widget.Button" resource-id="" text="" index="0"></node>
</nodes>
```

Comment: one more thing to ask, if I want to get a specific coordinates from a xml which has lot of nodes, what should I do? For example, there are lots of kinds of nodes in my xml file, but I only want get corrdinates of node which class is "button".

Comment: You can try something like this inside the for loop: `if node.getAttribute("class") == "button": print(node.getAttribute("bounds"))`